# Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, magento

I've stuck on installation of new Magento store... I searched a lot of sites over the night but I still can't find solution for my problem.

I receive the following errors:

> Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/Mage.php on line 50
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/code/local:/home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/code/community:/home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/code/core:/home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in /home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/Mage.php on line 50
>
> Warning: include(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
>   on line 68
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/code/local:/home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/code/community:/home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/code/core:/home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in
>   /home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
>   on line 68
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in
>   /home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/Mage.php:53 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/index.php(69): require_once()
>   #1 {main} thrown in /home/designed4gam/ftp/designed4gamers/app/Mage.php on line 53

The root folder of the site on FTP is: root/designed4gamers/

URL: www.designed4gamers.pl

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for all replies and advice!

Comment: When I Googled on _"Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream"_, I found several posts in different Magento forums. Have you checked those out? If yes, what did they tell you to do and what have you tried, just so people here don't spend time writing answers you've already tested.

Comment: I know, and I checked all these sites out but they are about different issues and not exactly what I am looking for. I found two posts looks similar to my issue but there was not answer to it... I looked up in my mage.php file but I didn't change any code mate...

Comment: If there were solutions that didn't fit your issue, please define those solutions and why they didn't work/could be applied.

Comment: For example I tried that advice: Re: Magento 1.9 Install Problem
Did you set your rewritebase to 'shop' in your .htaccess?
 
 
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root
#RewriteBase /magento/
but no successfully...

Comment: I've just deleted all files on FTP and uploaded again. Now it seems work well. Thanks anyway